# Calculating the Complexity of a Two Part Algorithm

Tags: asymptotics

This is in relation to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/108960/104858) post I made. I eventually solved this by the following approach:

1. Take the un-ordered file with all the purchasing data and use the UNIX `sort` utility to order the file on the customer identifier. Since the file can be 500 million lines (and grows over time) I used the `-T` option and directed the utility to use my hard drive to carry out it's sorting computation. The `sort` utility uses external sort to do the sorting.
2. I created a program which took this ordered file and in one pass computed the required values (a single for-loop, no nested for-loops)

Step 2 is O(n) clearly. But what about Step 1? What is the complexity here and more to the point of the question, what is the overall complexity of this two-stage solution?

Comment: The answer might depend on the algorithm that `sort` uses for "external sorting", whatever that means.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus http://vkundeti.blogspot.com/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html - the post says it is `Ω((N/M)log(N/M)/log(R))`. But how do I use this to compute the overall complexity?

Comment: Presumably you’re interested in an upper bound on the time complexity. Also, you haven’t stated what $M$ and $R$ are.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  , N is the size of the data to sort in bytes and M is the amount of 
 main memory on the machine (RAM). Yes, I am interested in the upper bound on the time complexity. The question really is what is the procedure to work out the overall complexity of two different algorithms combined together